# Integrating JIRA with Test Link using REST Interface

Tags: soapui, testlink, jira

I am trying to integrate Test Link (version 1.9.14) with my JIRA cloud instance.

I was earlier using the JIRA (interface- SOAP) to connect with JIRA, but wasn't successful, because JIRA, has deprecated SOAP interface after version 6.

So, I tried to configure using JIRA (interface- REST)

My configuration file is :

```
 <issuetracker>
 <username>my_username</username>
 <password>my_password</password>
 <uribase>https://myjirainstance.atlassian.net/</uribase>
 <!-- CRITIC - WITH HTTP getIssue() DOES NOT WORK -->
 <uriapi>https://myjirainstance.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/</uriapi>
<uriview>https://myjirainstance.atlassian.net/browse/</uriview>
<userinteraction>1</userinteraction>
<!-- 1: User will be able to manage following attributes from GUI -->  
<!-- Issue Type, Issue Priority, Affects Versions, Components -->
<!-- 0: values for attributes will be taken FROM this config XML from  GUI -->

<!-- Configure This if you want be able TO CREATE ISSUES -->
<projectkey>MYS</projectkey>
<issuetype>10004</issuetype>
</issuetracker>
```

After saving, I am seeing that the connection is still showing to be `KO` (not connected). 
The weird thing - I cannot see any error messages in the Events Logs.

I tried to check if my REST URI is correct, using SOAP-UI, . I used the URI

`https://myjirainstance.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/`

but it returned a 404 error.

Has anyone tried this linking before? If so, what am I doing wrong in the configuration.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you are not able to interact with jira's rest api using soapUI tool?

Comment: myjirainstance.atlassian.net is the service provided by Attlassian or you have some local instance of JIRA? If the latter you should give name of your host instead.

Comment: I have replaced this with my cloud instance already.

Comment: @Rao - yes the SOAP UI shows error for this REST URI.

Comment: @log_file, did some time ago successfully get data from jira. Have you looked at jira [documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/) for the same? Have you included the authentication?

Comment: Yes I looked at that but couldn't debug what was wrong. The authentication part is what I am also thinking is causing the issue. Can you have a sample of how you configured?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue .Could you please tell the final solution you applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've succesfully integrated TestLink 1.9.10 with Jira in the Cloud. My configuration for the issue tracker record in TestLink is:

```
    <!-- Template jirarestInterface -->

    <issuetracker>

    <username>USER</username>

    <password>XXXX/password>

    <uribase>https...baufest.atlassian.net/browse/PROJ</uribase>

    <!-- CRITIC - WITH HTTP getIssue() DOES NOT WORK -->

    <uriapi>https...baufest.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/</uriapi>

    <uriview>https...baufest.atlassian.net/browse/</uriview>

    <!-- Configure This if you want be able TO CREATE ISSUES -->

    <projectkey>PROJ</projectkey>

    <issuetype>1</issuetype>

    </issuetracker>
```

Where:

- USER is a valid Jira user that has permission to create bugs.
- PROJ is the Key of the Project in Jira where bugs are going to be created.
- Issue type is 1 because that's the issue type for the project PROJ that corresponds to bugs.
- "..." corresponds to "://" (I replaced it because the answer wouldn't save otherwise)

Hope this helps.

Regards!

Cecilia

(Baufest)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. But after spending some time looking into testlink source code,I was able to connect teslink 1.9.14 with JIRA using Rest Api.

Here is what I did,

Change hoststring  from "'user/search/?username='"  to "'user/?username='"  at line number 73 in File "/var/www/html/testlink/third_party/fayp-jira-rest/Jira.php".

As per JIRA Rest API to check whether user exist in system or not, the string should be http://Jirainstance/rest/api/latest/user/?username=JIRAUser.

Whereas Testlink is creating string as "http://Jirainstance/rest/api/latest/user/search/?username=JIRAUser. Which in result is returning a blank JSON, So testlink is returning connection as False. For me that is the cause of above problem.